# How can I get this word str_replace by PHP

Tags: php

I want to replace the `<a href='http://example.org/'>this word</a>` element. But the problem is that "**this word**" can be any word.

```
<?php
   $link = "http://example.com";
   $site = file_get_contents($link);
   $ades = "<a href='http://example.org/'>this word</a>";
   $bdes = "";
   $site = str_replace($ades,$bdes,$site);
   echo $site;
?>
```

**'This word'** is a variable

**'This word'** can be pink, blue, door etc.

How can I get it?

edited :

**I just want to remove like these codes**

```
<a href="example.org/">blaasdsad</a>
<a href="example.org/">gertvb</a>
<a href="example.org/">ertvvuyrt</a>
<a href="example.org/">awceawce</a>
<a href="example.org/">8k9789k789k</a>
```

and else

Comment: You want to remove the link where the link text is "this word"?

Comment: yes I will remove the links with words

Comment: example `<a href="http://example.org">Blue</a>, <a href="http://example.org">sky</a>`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ades = "<a href='http://example.org/'>this word</a>";
echo strip_tags($ades);
```

Just use *strip_tags* function to remove the html tags. The output will be a string with the color name.

More info about strip_tags [Here!!!](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to access every tag of your actual page which has this form `<a href='http://example.org/'>any text or word</a>`, I would use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace.php), which use a pattern to detect what to change (instead of a string).

For your string, it would render something like that:

```
<?php
    $link = "http://example.com";
    $site = file_get_contents($link);
    // use a pattern
    $ades = "/^<a href='http:\/\/example\.org\/'>.*<\/a>$/";
    $bdes = "";
    // use other function
    $site = preg_replace($ades,$bdes,$site);
    echo $site;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$var="blue";
$ades = "<a href='http://example.org/'>".$var."</a>";
$shortAdes=substr($ades,strpos($ades,$var),strlen($var));
echo $shortAdes;
```

it weill print the $var